# Linuxで7文字以下の行をファイルから削除したい

Tags: linux

Linuxでファイル内の文字数が7以下の行を削除して、8文字以上だけにしたいのですが、調べてもどのコマンドを組み合わせて実行すればいいのか分かりません。

例
a.txt

```
aaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa        
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aa
```

↓
a.txt

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

こんな感じにしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問文にある様な結果を得るとすれば、「行末の空白文字類は除いて8文字以下の行を削除」(3行目には `a` が8文字あります)となるので、grep を使って、`grep -E '^.{8,}[^[:space:]][[:space:]]*$' a.txt` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確かに3行目が8文字になっていました。確認不足です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

空白を考慮せず、単純に7文字以下の行を削除する方法です。

```
cat a.txt | sed '
/^$/d
/^.$/d
/^..$/d
/^...$/d
/^....$/d
/^.....$/d
/^......$/d
/^.......$/d
'
```

以下の記述を追加すれば、行末の空白を削除できます。

```
s/[ ][ ]*$//
```

---

ファイルを書き換える版です。exを使っています。

```
ex a.txt <<EOF
/^.......$/d
/^......$/d
/^.....$/d
/^....$/d
/^...$/d
/^..$/d
/^.$/d
/^$/d
x
EOF
```

以下の記述を追加すれば、行末の空白を削除できます。

```
 %s/[ ][ ]*$//
```

Comment: 複数の回答を頂き、ありがとうございます。私が求めていた結果に最も適していたのはこちらの回答でしたので、ベストアンサーとしました。

Answer (score 7):

たくさんあるよ。

### sed

```
sed -ne '/.\{8\}/p' a.txt
```

### perl

```
perl -nle 'print if length > 7' a.txt
```

### awk

```
awk 'length > 7' a.txt
```

### grep

```
grep '.\{8\}' a.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

説明と期待する結果が一致していないような気がしますが、行末の空白を `sed` で削除しつつ `awk` を使うと以下のようなワンライナーは如何でしょうか。

```
$ cat a.txt | sed 's/\s*$//' | awk '{ if(length($0) >= 8){ print } }'
```

Answer (score 2):

**残す** ではなく **消す** というアプローチで書いてみました。

```sh
$ grep -E -v '^.{0,7}$' a.txt
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

$ sed -E '/^.{0,7}$/d' a.txt
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```